# How to rerun Migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, schema

Hey I have an issue I am trying to do few things in rails. I am trying to edit the migration files to change few column and tables name. But I can see there is rollback option for this and reset but when I do rollback it require version and when I do reset drop or setup it loads the schema . Is there any way by which my application can run all the migration again and create new schema .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind losing all the data, you can run

```
rake db:drop
```

BIG CAVEAT - this will delete your database and all your data.

Then you can run

```
rake db:create db:migrate
```

If this is a new app, exists solely on your localhost i.e. has not been deployed to production, and you don't mind losing all your data, then this option is fine.

Generally, I would recommend not amending your migrations but creating new ones to change column names etc.

Comment: you can do it in one line: rake db:reset db:migrate